# Flexbox align column to the right if there is only one column

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a two column flexbox layout. However, sometimes there is only one column, in which case the column should be aligned to the right. Currently the column is aligned to the left.

https://codepen.io/sleepydada/pen/rzVRxL

HTML:

```
<div class="answers">
  <div class="answer">first answer</div>
  <div class="answer">second answer</div>
</div>
<div class="answers">
  <div class="answer">first answer</div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.answers {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;

  &:first-of-type {
    background: #ccc;
  }

  .answer {
    background: crimson;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this CSS:

```
.answer:only-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type)

> The :only-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has no
>   siblings of the same type.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/solbreslin/pen/KvpEmp)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.answers {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.answers:first-of-type {
  background: #ccc;
}

.answers .answer {
  background: crimson;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
}

.answers .answer:only-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="answers">
  <div class="answer">first answer</div>
  <div class="answer">second answer</div>
</div>
<div class="answers">
  <div class="answer">first answer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an invisible div with `height` set to `0`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.invisible {
  height: 0;
  border: none !important;
}

.answers {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.answers:first-of-type {
  background: #ccc;
}
.answers .answer {
  background: crimson;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="answers">
  <div class="answer">first answer</div>
  <div class="answer invisible"><!--invisible div--></div>
  <div class="answer">second answer</div>
</div>
<div class="answers">
  <div class="answer invisible"><!--invisible div--></div>
  <div class="answer">first answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion, it would be an example of bad practice.

Comment: I agree that this might be over kill for this question but the concept can be handy in some cases.